# Show/hide (duplicate independently) 1000 sentences (and keeping good browser/host performances)

Tags: javascript, jquery, performance, duplicates, clone

I've made JQuery scripts tests to **show/hide (duplicate) the future sentences of my page** (*1000 to duplicate independently*) so I'm looking for the **lightest way** (for browser/host) to do so.

Here is 2 classic/functional solutions I've already wrote.

- In your point of view what would be the best solution ?
- Do you see an other/better solution to reach my need please ? Maybe using variables and increments but not sure how to do so yet.

Thank you for your advices!

- **1 (addClass/removeClass + will have to write 1000 x 2 sentences)** =

https://jsfiddle.net/mb6g0u3d/

```js
$(function(){
// script for sentence1
$("#button1show").click(function(){
$("#sentence1").removeClass("hide");
$("#button1show").addClass("hide")});
$("#button1hide").click(function(){
$("#sentence1").addClass("hide");
$("#button1show").removeClass("hide")});

// script for sentence2
$("#button2show").click(function(){
$("#sentence2").removeClass("hide");
$("#button2show").addClass("hide")});
$("#button2hide").click(function(){
$("#sentence2").addClass("hide");
$("#button2show").removeClass("hide")})
})
```

```css
.hide {
display:none;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.5.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<!-- sentences to show somewhere else -->
sentence1<br />
<button id="button1show">show there</button>
<br /><br />
sentence2<br />
<button id="button2show">show there</button>

<hr />

<!-- somewhere else -->
<div id="sentence1" class="hide">
sentence1<br />
<button id="button1hide">hide here</button>
</div>
<br />
<div id="sentence2" class="hide">
sentence2<br />
<button id="button2hide">hide here</button>
</div>
```

- **2 (addClass/removeClass/clone + will have to write 1000 sentences only)** =

https://jsfiddle.net/L7q2juce/

```js
// script for sentence1
$("#button1show").on("click", function() {
$("#button1hide").removeClass("hide");
$("#button1show").addClass("hide");
$('#sentence1tocopy').clone().addClass('cloned1').attr('id',null).appendTo('#clonehere1')});
$("#button1hide").on("click", function() {
$("#button1show").removeClass("hide");
$("#button1hide").addClass("hide");
$('.cloned1').remove()});

// script for sentence2
$("#button2show").on("click", function() {
$("#button2hide").removeClass("hide");
$("#button2show").addClass("hide");
$('#sentence2tocopy').clone().addClass('cloned2').attr('id',null).appendTo('#clonehere2')});
$("#button2hide").on("click", function() {
$("#button2show").removeClass("hide");
$("#button2hide").addClass("hide");
$('.cloned2').remove()})
```

```css
.hide {
display:none;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.5.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<!-- sentences to show somewhere else -->
<div id="sentence1tocopy">sentence1</div><button id="button1show">show there</button>
<br /><br />
<div id="sentence2tocopy">sentence2</div><button id="button2show">show there</button>

<hr />

<!-- somewhere else -->
<div id="clonehere1"></div><button class="hide" id="button1hide">hide here</button>
<br /><br />
<div id="clonehere2"></div><button class="hide" id="button2hide">hide here</button>
```

Answer (score 1):

Data attributes can allow you to do it without repeating code.

```js
$("[data-toggles]").on("click", function (){
  var btn = $(this);
  var selector = btn.data('toggles');
  $(selector).toggleClass("hide");
});
```

```css
.hide {
  display: none;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<!-- sentences to show somewhere else -->
sentence1 <button data-toggles="#sentence1">show there</button>
<br /> sentence2 <button data-toggles="#sentence2">show there</button>

<hr />

<!-- somewhere else -->
<div id="sentence1" class="hide">
  sentence1 <button data-toggles="#sentence1">hide here</button>
</div>
<div id="sentence2" class="hide">
  sentence2 <button data-toggles="#sentence2">hide here</button>
</div>
```

If you want it to make sure it shows/hides, add another attribute

```js
$("[data-shows]").on("click", function (){
  var btn = $(this);
  var selector = btn.data('shows');
  $(selector).removeClass("hide");
});

$("[data-hides]").on("click", function (){
  var btn = $(this);
  var selector = btn.data('hides');
  $(selector).addClass("hide");
});
```

```css
.hide {
  display: none;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<!-- sentences to show somewhere else -->
sentence1 <button data-shows="#sentence1">show there</button>
<br /> sentence2 <button data-shows="#sentence2">show there</button>

<hr />

<!-- somewhere else -->
<div id="sentence1" class="hide">
  sentence1 <button data-hides="#sentence1">hide here</button>
</div>
<div id="sentence2" class="hide">
  sentence2 <button data-hides="#sentence2">hide here</button>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

Thank you for that HTML5 tips @epascarello ! I didn't know about that data-* stuffs, it is very nice. I have added an highlighting for the selected sentences.

```js
// add phrase (dans zone phrase collée) (quand clic bouton add)
$("[data-shows]").on("click", function (){
var btn = $(this);
var selector = btn.data('shows');
$(selector).removeClass("hide");
});
// remove phrase (de zone phrase collée) (quand clic bouton remove)
$("[data-hides]").on("click", function (){
var btn = $(this);
var selector = btn.data('hides');
$(selector).addClass("hide");
});

// add fond jaune (zone) + remove pink (zone) (quand clic bouton add)
$("[data-addcouleurjaune]").on("click", function (){
var btn = $(this);
var selector = btn.data('addcouleurjaune');
$(selector).removeClass("pink");
$(selector).addClass("yellow");
});
// remove fond jaune (zone) + remove pink (zone) (quand clic bouton remove)
$("[data-removecouleurjaune]").on("click", function (){
var btn = $(this);
var selector = btn.data('removecouleurjaune');
$(selector).removeClass("yellow");
$(selector).removeClass("pink");
});

// add fond rose (zone) + remove fond jaune (zone) (quand clic fond rose (zone))
$("[data-dzonephrase1archive]").on("click", function (){
var btn = $(this);
var selector = btn.data('dzonephrase1archive');
$(selector).removeClass("yellow");
$(selector).addClass("pink");
});

// remove phrase (de zone phrase collée) (quand clic fond rose (zone))
$("[data-dphrasedupliquee]").on("click", function (){
var btn = $(this);
var selector = btn.data('dphrasedupliquee');
$(selector).addClass("hide");
});
```

```css
.hide {
display:none;
}

.yellow {
background-color:yellow;
}

.pink {
background-color:pink;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.5.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<!-- ADD -->
PHRASE1<br />
montrer : <button
data-shows="#sentence1"
data-addcouleurjaune="#zonephrase1archive">clic</button>
<br />
cacher : <button
data-hides="#sentence1"
data-removecouleurjaune="#zonephrase1archive"
>clic</button>

<div id="zonephrase1archive" data-dzonephrase1archive="#zonephrase1archive" data-dphrasedupliquee="#sentence1">phrase1 à duppliquer</div>

<br /><hr />

PHRASE2<br />
montrer : <button
data-shows="#sentence2"
data-addcouleurjaune="#zonephrase2archive">clic</button>
<br />
cacher : <button
data-hides="#sentence2"
data-removecouleurjaune="#zonephrase2archive"
>clic</button>

<div id="zonephrase2archive" data-dzonephrase1archive="#zonephrase2archive" data-dphrasedupliquee="#sentence2">phrase2 à duppliquer</div>

<br /><hr /><hr /><hr />

<!-- REMOVE -->
<div id="sentence1" class="hide">
phrase1 à duppliquer
</div>

<br /><hr />

<div id="sentence2" class="hide">
phrase2 à duppliquer
</div>
```

And I am still searching to add the clone() JQuery method to have only 1000 sentences (not to have to write them 2 times). Problem: Clicking buttons show 1 sentence type only, I don't know how to show the good ones only.

```js
// add phrase (dans zone phrase collée) (quand clic bouton add)
$("[data-shows]").on("click", function (){
var btn = $(this);
var selector = btn.data('shows');
$(selector).removeClass("hide");
$('.cloned1').remove();
});
// remove phrase (de zone phrase collée) (quand clic bouton remove)
$("[data-hides]").on("click", function (){
var btn = $(this);
var selector = btn.data('hides');
$(selector).addClass("hide");
});

// add fond jaune (zone) + remove pink (zone) (quand clic bouton add)
$("[data-addcouleurjaune]").on("click", function (){
var btn = $(this);
var selector = btn.data('addcouleurjaune');
$(selector).clone().addClass('cloned1').attr('id',null).appendTo($('[data-ici]'));
$(selector).removeClass("pink");
$(selector).addClass("yellow");
});
// remove fond jaune (zone) + remove pink (zone) (quand clic bouton remove)
$("[data-removecouleurjaune]").on("click", function (){
var btn = $(this);
var selector = btn.data('removecouleurjaune');
$(selector).removeClass("yellow");
$(selector).removeClass("pink");
});

// add fond rose (zone) + remove fond jaune (zone) (quand clic fond rose (zone))
$("[data-dzonephrase1archive]").on("click", function (){
var btn = $(this);
var selector = btn.data('dzonephrase1archive');
$(selector).removeClass("yellow");
$(selector).addClass("pink");
});

// remove phrase (de zone phrase collée) (quand clic fond rose (zone))
$("[data-dphrasedupliquee]").on("click", function (){
var btn = $(this);
var selector = btn.data('dphrasedupliquee');
$(selector).addClass("hide");
});
```

```css
.hide {
display: none;
content-visibility:hidden;
}

.yellow {
background-color:yellow;
}

.pink {
background-color:pink;
}

.cloned1 {
background-color:white;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.5.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<!-- ADD -->
PHRASE1<br />
montrer : <button
data-shows="#sentence1"
data-addcouleurjaune="#zonephrase1archive">clic</button>
<br />
cacher : <button
data-hides="#sentence1"
data-removecouleurjaune="#zonephrase1archive"
>clic</button>

<div id="zonephrase1archive" data-dzonephrase1archive="#zonephrase1archive" data-dphrasedupliquee="#sentence1">phrase1 à duppliquer</div>

<br /><hr />

PHRASE2<br />
montrer : <button
data-shows="#sentence2"
data-addcouleurjaune="#zonephrase2archive">clic</button>
<br />
cacher : <button
data-hides="#sentence2"
data-removecouleurjaune="#zonephrase2archive"
>clic</button>

<div id="zonephrase2archive" data-dzonephrase1archive="#zonephrase2archive" data-dphrasedupliquee="#sentence2">phrase2 à duppliquer</div>

<br /><hr /><hr /><hr />

<!-- REMOVE -->
<div id="sentence1" class="hide">
<div id="ici1" data-ici="#ici1"></div>
</div>

<br /><hr />

<div id="sentence2" class="hide">
<div id="ici2" data-ici="#ici2"></div>
</div>
```